# How to get property from stub function argument?

Tags: php, testing, phpspec

I have a service, which should create an email class object and pass it to the third class (email-sender).

I want to check body of email, which generates by the function.

Service.php

```
class Service
{
    /** @var EmailService */
    protected $emailService;

    public function __construct(EmailService $emailService)
    {
        $this->emailService = $emailService;
    }

    public function testFunc()
    {
        $email = new Email();
        $email->setBody('abc'); // I want to test this attribute

        $this->emailService->send($email);
    }
}
```

Email.php:

```
class Email
{
    protected $body;

    public function setBody($body)
    {
        $this->body = $body;
    }
    public function getBody()
    {
        return $this->body;
    }
}
```

EmailService.php

```
interface EmailService
{
    public function send(Email $email);
}
```

So I create a stub class for emailService and email. But I can't validate the body of the email. I also can't check if $email->setBody() was called, because email is created inside the tested function

```
class ServiceSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    function it_creates_email_with_body_abc(EmailService $emailService, Email $email)
    {
        $this->beConstructedWith($emailService);

        $emailService->send($email);
        $email->getBody()->shouldBe('abc');
        $this->testFunc();
    }
}
```

I got this:

```
Call to undefined method Prophecy\Prophecy\MethodProphecy::shouldBe() in /private/tmp/phpspec/spec/App/ServiceSpec.php on line 18
```

In real app the body is generated, so I want to test, if it's generated correctly. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHPSpec you can't make this kind of assertion onto created objects (and even on stubs or mocks as you create them in spec file): only thing you can match on are SUS (**S**ystem **U**nder **S**pec) and its returned value (if any).

I'm gonna write a little guide to make your test pass **and** to improve your design and testability

---

## What's wrong from my point of view

`new` usage inside `Service`

## Why is wrong

`Service` has two responsibility: create an `Email` object and do its job. This break SRP of [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)). Moreover you lost control over object creation and this become, as you spotted, very difficult to test

## Workaround to make spec pass

I would recommend to use a factory (as I will show below) for this kind of task because increase testability dramatically but, in this case, you can make your test pass by rewriting the spec as follows

```
class ServiceSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    function it_creates_email_with_body_abc(EmailService $emailService) 
    { 
        $this->beConstructedWith($emailService);

        //arrange data
        $email = new Email();
        $email->setBody('abc');

        //assert
        $emailService->send($email)->shouldBeCalled();

        //act
        $this->testFunc();
    }
}
```

As long as `setBody` does not change in SUS implementation, this works.
However I would not recommend it as this should be a smell from PHPSpec point of view.

## Use a factory

Create the factory

```
class EmailFactory()
{
    public function createEmail($body)
    {
        $email = new Email();
        $email->setBody($body);

        return $email;
    }
}
```

and its spec

```
public function EmailFactorySpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    function it_is_initializable()
    {
        $this->shouldHaveType(EmailFactory::class);
    }

    function it_creates_email_with_body_content()
    {
        $body = 'abc';
        $email = $this->createEmail($body);

        $email->shouldBeAnInstanceOf(Email::class);
        $email->getBody()->shouldBeEqualTo($body);
    }
}
```

Now you're sure that `createEmail` of the factory does what you expect to do. As you can notice, responsibility is incapsulated here and you don't need to worry elsewhere (think about a strategy where you can choose how to send mails: directly, putting them in a queue and so on; if you tackle them with original approach, you need to test in every concrete strategy that email is created as you expected whereas now you don't).

## Integrate the factory in SUS

```
class Service
{
    /** @var EmailService */
    protected $emailService;

    /** @var EmailFactory */
    protected $emailFactory;

    public function __construct(
      EmailService $emailService, EmailFactory $emailFactory
    ) {
        $this->emailService = $emailService;
        $this->emailFactory = $emailFactory;
    }

    public function testFunc()
    {
        $email = $this->emailFactory->createEmail('abc');
        $this->emailService->send($email);
    } 
}
```

## Finally make spec pass (the right way)

```
function it_creates_email_with_body_abc(
  EmailService $emailService, EmailFactory $emailFactory, Email $mail
) {
    $this->beConstructedWith($emailService);
    // if you need to be sure that body will be 'abc', 
    // otherwise you can use Argument::type('string') wildcard
    $emailFactory->createEmail('abc')->willReturn($email);
    $emailService->send($email)->shouldBeCalled();

    $this->testFunc();
}
```

I did not tried myself this examples and there could be some typos but I'm 100% sure of this approach: I hope is clear for all readers.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate!

Comment: I've uploaded working code here: https://gist.github.com/xorik/89da2c3c065d1b6b6d10d915191305f2