# phpspec - check if a method was called with a specific argument (object)

Tags: php, phpspec

I am writing a PHPspec test where want to test if a method was called with the correct argument (in the case an object).

I am doing something like this (pseudo code), inside my spec:

```
function it_some_test(MyService $myservice) {
    $object = new MyDomainObject();
    $object->setPropertyX("some value")

    $myservice->getSomething($object)->shouldBeCalled();
```

}

The object is just a DTO created inside my service. Its created exactly the same way in the original Service. Just the value of some properties change based on same logic. thats what I want to test.

The problem is my test is always failing because it says the $object is different from what it was excepting but they have exactly the same properties values.

How does PHPspec compares objects? If I pass Argument::any() instead it works but I need to test the object passed as a property with a specific value.

Comment: checkout this answer that could help you as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307939/how-to-get-property-from-stub-function-argument

However, if values are ALL the same, it should pass even if this not recommended to keep in the same class an object implementation and its usage

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I was calling the method ->shouldBeCalled() before calling the real method under test. Change the order and it works now.